# How to draw a graph with duplicate edges in networkx in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I need to draw a graph with duplicate edges (i.e., more than one edge between 2 nodes). I tried:

```
import networkx as nx
edges = [(0, 1), (0, 1)]

G = nx.DiGraph ()
G.add_edges_from (edges)

print G.edges ()
#[(0, 1)]
```

Duplicate entries are simply discarded. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: its pretty easy to just generate your own DOT source ... not sure how you would do it with networkx

Comment: @JoranBeasley Can you elaborate on DOT source? :-)

Comment: http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language  ( see : https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1498108430658#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%20%20a%20-%3E%20b%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22foo%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20a%20-%3E%20b%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22bar%22%20%5D%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no expert on `networkx` either but, according to the documentation [here](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#multigraphs):

> **Multigraphs**   NetworkX provides classes for graphs which allow
>   multiple edges between any pair of nodes. The MultiGraph and
>   MultiDiGraph classes allow you to add the same edge twice, possibly
>   with different edge data. This can be powerful for some applications,
>   but many algorithms are not well defined on such graphs. Shortest path
>   is one example. Where results are well defined, e.g.
>   MultiGraph.degree() we provide the function. Otherwise you should
>   convert to a standard graph in a way that makes the measurement well
>   defined.

Thus, the example should work if one change is made - create `G` as follows:

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
```